# record "new" has no field "cure" postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

so here's the thing,I have two tables: apointments(with a single p) and medical_folder and i get this

> ERROR:  record "new" has no field "cure"
>   CONTEXT:  SQL statement "insert into medical_folder(id,"patient_AMKA",cure,drug_id)
>   values(new.id,new."patient_AMKA",new.cure,new.drug_id)"
>   PL/pgSQL function new_medical() line 3 at SQL statement

```
create trigger example_trigger after insert on apointments 
for each row execute procedure new_medical();

create or replace function new_medical()
returns trigger as $$
begin 
if apointments.diagnosis is not null then
insert into medical_folder(id,"patient_AMKA",cure,drug_id)
values(new.id,new."patient_AMKA",new.cure,new.drug_id);
return new;
end if;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;


insert into apointments(id,time,"patient_AMKA","doctor_AMKA",diagnosis)
values('30000','2017-05-24 0 
07:42:15','4017954515276','6304745877947815701','M3504');
```

I have checked multiple times and all of my tables and columns are existing
Please help!Thank you!

Table structures are:

```
create table medical_folder (
  id      bigInt,
  patient bigInt,
  cure    text,
  drug_id bigInt);

create table apointments (
  id      bigint,
  time    timestamp without time zone,
  "patient_AMKA" bigInt,
  "doctor_AMKA"  bigInt);
```

Comment: I'm using pgAdmin 4 by the way!

Comment: As the message states, medical_folder does not have a column called "cure". Check your schema again. Without your schemas, we wont be able to help you beyond that.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention them:
the table medical_folder is:
id(bigInt) 
patient(bigInt) 
cure(text) 
drug_id(bigInt)

and table apointments is:
id(bigint)
time(timestamp without time zone)
"patient_AMKA"(bigInt)
"doctor_AMKA"(bigInt)
but I have checked my schemas and column "cure" does exist!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I was facing the same issue.
Change:

```
values(new.id,new."patient_AMKA",new.cure,new.drug_id);
```

to:

```
values(new.id,new."patient_AMKA",new."cure",new."drug_id");
```

Answer (score 1):

This error means the table apointments (with 1 p) doesn't have a field named cure. The trigger occurs when inserting an apointment, so "new" is an apointment row. Maybe it is part of the diagnosis object?

The values for the second table are not available in the "new" row. You need a way to get and insert them, and using a trigger is not the easiest/clean way to go.
You can have your application do two inserts, one by table, and wrap them in a transaction to ensure they are both committed/rolled back. Another option, which lets you better enforce the data integrity, is to create a stored procedure that takes the values to be inserted in both tables and do the two inserts. You can go as far as forbidding user to write to the tables, effectively leaving the stored procedure the only way to insert the data.

Comment: actually the filed "cure" belongs to table medical_folder,so I guess I'm missing something big...sorry I'm new to SQL but what I am trying to do is to first insert data into table "apointments" and then into table "medical_folder" through the trigger..Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where are the cure/drug_id values coming from? Are they already in a table -> fetch the value and insert. From a user input? -> don't insert from the trigger but have your application do two regular inserts or use a stored procedure to do them

Comment: The data input is done from the user but the whole thing is part of an assignment that requires me to use triggers and functions